# How to remove duplicate values by comparing two array type column values in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, array-column

I want to remove duplicate values by comparing two array type column values.

I want to get the result of subtracting the fruit I already ate from my favorite fruit.
But if there ara 2 apples in your favorite fruit column and 1 apple in eaten fruit column, I'd like to leave 1 apple in favorite fruit column.

how to get this result?

I don't know the answer no matter how hard I think about it.

### table : favorite

### idx   |   favorite_fruit          |  fruit_eaten

```
1     | {apple,banana,orange}         | {apple,orange}
```

---

```
2     | {apple,apple,banana,orange}   | {apple,banana,orange}
```

### The result I want

### idx   |  Result

```
1     | {banana}
```

---

```
2     | {apple}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways to do this, but here's my five minute stab at it:

```
SELECT
    array_agg(remaining.fruit) AS remaining_favorites
FROM (
    SELECT
        fruit, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY fruit) AS ordinal
    FROM
        unnest('{apple,apple,banana,orange}'::text[]) favortites (fruit)
    EXCEPT
    SELECT
        fruit, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY fruit) AS ordinal
    FROM
        unnest('{apple, banana, orange}'::text[]) eaten (fruit)) remaining;
```

Comment: I appreciate for your anwer.
I solved my problum utilizing your answer.